# Input type="number" error value "{{}}" cannot be parsed, or is out of range with handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I have a warning when I set a value into a input type="number" tag with handlebars.js.

The html of the template is:

```
<input id="i-f" type="number" class="form-control full-width" value="{{m_f}}" />
```

and I pass the following value:

```
objname = {
m_f: 3
}
```

When the handlebars template is loaded the console show me this warning:

> The specified value "{{m_f}}" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.

I've already tried to set the value with and without the double quotes (") and with a third curly brackets but nothing changes. I don't understand where I'm doing wrong.

The value is set right even with this warning but how can i fix it?

I'm using handlebars 4.7.7 and jquery 2.2.4

Sorry for my potato eglish :P, i hope I was clear. Thank you!

**EDIT**

The call for handlebars template is:

Built-in function

```
 LoadDeviceTemplate(options.data, selector, options.templateURL, true, options.selector, false);
```

That run:

```
var template = GetHBTemplate(urlHtml, innerSelector);
```

where is runned the ajax call for the .html file

```
$.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: urlHtml + "?ts=" + daysfromepoch
        cache: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var $d = $(data);
                            
            var scriptid = null,scriptSelIsPresent = 0 ,onlyScriptSel=0;
            if ($d.is("script[type='text/x-handlebars-template']")) {
                

                scriptid = $d.filter("script").attr("id");
                if ((innerSelector + " ").indexOf("#" + scriptid + " ") == 0) {
                    scriptSelIsPresent = 1;
                    if (innerSelector.length == scriptid.length + 1)
                       
                        onlyScriptSel=1;
                }
        
                
                if (scriptSelIsPresent) {
                    if (onlyScriptSel) {                            
                        shtml = $d.text();                            
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    innerSelector = innerSelector.substring(("#" + scriptid + " ").length);                          
                   
                }
                $d = $($d.text());
            }
            var $f = $d.filter(innerSelector);

            if ($f.length > 0) {
                if ($f.attr("type") == "text/x-handlebars-template")
                    shtml = $f.html();
                else
                    shtml = $f[0].outerHTML;
            }
            else {
                var complexSelector = innerSelector.indexOf("=") >= 0;
                var arr = innerSelector.split(" ");
                var id = arr.shift();
                if (!complexSelector && arr.length > 0 && $d.filter(id).length)
                    shtml = $($d.filter(id).html()).find(arr.join(" "))[0].outerHTML;
                else
                    shtml = $d.find(innerSelector)[0].outerHTML;
            }
        }
    });
```

The warning appears when is runned the line "$d = $($d.text());"

Comment: Can we see the code that calls the template function?

Comment: @76484 hi, i've just updated the thread. Do you need more more information?

Comment: Grazie. What are `LoadDeviceTemplate` and `GetHBTemplate`? Are these functions that you have created?

Comment: There is _a lot_ going on here and I find it difficult to follow. Most importantly, I don't see where your Handlebars template function gets compiled (`Handlebars.compile`). So it's not clear to me that Handlebars is even being used here.

Comment: @76484 sorry mate, i forgot to copy paste the last row of GetHBTemplate that is:
        return Handlebars.compile(shtml);

the template returned will be completed in LoadDeviceTemplate with this comand

 $(selector).append(template(dev));

dev is the object with the values to put into the handlebars template

i hope i didn't forget somethings else this time

Answer (score 0):

This warning is not being given by Handlebars, but by jQuery. It is a valid warning because with the code `$d = $($d.text());` you are asking jQuery to parse an `<input>` element with `[type="number"]` and `[value="{{m_f}}"]`. jQuery knows that `{{m_f}}` is *not* a valid number and so it is warning you about this fact.

In your case, it is acceptable to have `{{m_f}}` as the value of the `input[type="number"]` element because you are going to take the stringified representation of this element and submit it to Handlebars to create a template function.

Therefore, I think it is valid and reasonable for you to ignore this warning from jQuery.

As a reader of your code, I am inclined to suggest that it could be simplified so as to be much easier to read and understand. I think it is quite possible that you do not need to be re-wrapping your template in jQuery so many times and you could perhaps be able to refactor away the `$d = $($d.text());` that is producing the warning. However, I am not able to comprehend all of the filtering and finding your are doing later in the function so as to able to re-write this functionality for you.